# How to concatenation values from string into value in variable?

Tags: php, javascript, dynamic-forms, dynamicform

I am currently working in Open cart frame work. In that Open Cart, Dynamic forms are present.In that Dynamic form, so the script also dynamic, I have to calculate when the form data changes. during this i am getting some problem. I am getting select box option values in dynamically....

```
foreach ($options as $option) {  $initiates_f=$initiates_f+1; ?>    
       <?php if ($option['type'] == 'select'){ ?>   

            var a_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>= document.getElementById("option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]").value;
            var spl_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>  = a_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>.split("_");
            var cr_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>   = spl_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>[1];
            var operator3_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>    = cr_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>.split("[");
            var symbol<?php echo $initiates_f;?> = operator3_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>[0];
            var dtt_<?php echo $initiates_f;?> =  operator3_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>[1];
            var myarr_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>        = dtt_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>.split("$");
            var symbol_st_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>    = myarr_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>[1];
            var split_value_<?php echo $initiates_f;?> = myarr_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>[1];
            var final_value_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>  =symbol_st_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>.split(".");
            var Final_price<?php echo $initiates_f;?>   =final_value_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>[0];


    <?php  }    } ?>
```

further, I am assigning that Final_price value into some variable outside for loop.Here this script coding...

```
    var total_amount=0;
                    for(var i=1; i<=j; i++)
                    {alert('test');

                             final_prices=("Final_price"+i).value;
                            alert(final_prices);
alert(symbol_prices.value);*/
                            if(isNumber(final_prices)){
                                alert("number");
                                /*if(symbol_prices =='+') {
                                        alert("plus");
                                 var total_amount+=parseInt(original_prices)+parseInt(final_prices);
                                 calculated_price_element.innerHTML=total_amount;
                                 alert(total_amount);
                            } else if(symbol_prices =='-') {
                                    alert("minus");
                                 var total_amount+=parseInt(original_prices)-parseInt(final_prices);
                                 calculated_price_element.innerHTML=total_amount;
                                  alert(total_amount);
                            }*/
                     //alert('test');

                    }

                }
```

In that coding `final_prices=("Final_price"+i).value;` does not return value from that assigned variable,How to get this value..please solve it..I am struggling for 2 days..
any other alternative solutions for this....please guide me...

Comment: Javascript works on the client side (in this case) - so we need to see the rendered script, not your `<?php echo ... ?>` tags.

Comment: I'd recommend using an array or object for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got solutions for this....please follow this its more useful for other...
I concluded with php and java-script...

```
 foreach ($options as $option) {  $initiates_f=$initiates_f+1; ?>   
       <?php if ($option['type'] == 'select'){ ?>   

            var a_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>= document.getElementById("option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]").value;
            var spl_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>  = a_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>.split("_");
            var cr_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>   = spl_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>[1];
            var operator3_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>    = cr_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>.split("[");
            var symbol<?php echo $initiates_f;?> = operator3_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>[0];
            var dtt_<?php echo $initiates_f;?> =  operator3_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>[1];
            var myarr_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>        = dtt_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>.split("$");
            var symbol_st_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>    = myarr_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>[1];
            var split_value_<?php echo $initiates_f;?> = myarr_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>[1];
            var final_value_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>  =symbol_st_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>.split(".");
            var Final_price<?php echo $initiates_f;?>   =final_value_<?php echo $initiates_f;?>[0];


    <?php  }    } 

    echo 'var final_prices=0;';

       $initiates_f=0;
       foreach ($options as $option) {  $initiates_f=$initiates_f+1; 
       if ($option['type'] == 'select')
    {
    echo 'final_prices=parseInt(Final_price'.$initiates_f.');';
        echo    "total_amount+=parseInt(final_prices);
                    // alert(total_amount);
                 calculated_price_element.innerHTML=total_amount;";

     }
     }
    ?>
```

Thank u...